# Read/Write to same file using csv.dictreader python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code which takes a `csv` file and chops out only the columns that match the `fields` list.

```
def mi_columnDeleter(filenameWithPath):
    #The fields I want
    fields = ["Part Number", "Full MI", "Accepts", "Attempts"]

    #Open the file
    infile = codecs.open(filenameWithPath, 'rb')    
    #hook the DictReader
    r = csv.DictReader(infile)
    #error occurs here because I have it before 'r' below
    infile.close()
    #open the same file
    outfile = open(filenameWithPath, "wb")
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fields, extrasaction="ignore")
    w.writeheader()
    for row in r:
        w.writerow(row)
    outfile.close()
```

I get the following I/O error `I/O operation on closed file` because I have `infile.close()` before I use `r`.

My question is there a way to read in the csv data - chop it down to the correct columns - then save it back to the same file?

I know there are workarounds but I'm sure that python should be able to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reopen the same file for writing you need to store the rows in a list first, you cannot close the file and then try to iterate over the lines:

```
 r = csv.DictReader(infile)
 r = list(r)
 ..........
```

A better approach would be writing to a [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), using [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to replace the original file after updating:

```
from shutil import move
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import csv
import os

def mi_columnDeleter(filenameWithPath):
    fields = ["Part Number", "Full MI", "Accepts", "Attempts"]
    with codecs.open(filenameWithPath, 'rb') as f, NamedTemporaryFile("w",dir=".", delete=False) as temp:
        r = csv.DictReader(f)
        w = csv.DictWriter(temp, fields, extrasaction="ignore")
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerows(r)
    move(temp.name,filenameWithPath)
```

Using as input:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

and fields defined as  `fields = ["a","c"]` would output:

```
a,c
1,3
4,6
```

You can also simply call `writerows` passing in the reader object with using the for loop in your own code.

Comment: First -  thank you for your help! Second, Help me understand why that would be a better approach, I am genuinely interested in learning.

Comment: @TangoAlee, if your code errors, your comp dies  etc.. you would lose all your data after you open the file a second time using `wb`, also at least on linux the `move(temp.name,filenameWithPath)` is atomic. That and it is pretty readable